# Sine Fourier Series? How do I get to this answer?

Tags: calculus, fourier-series

Calculate the
Sine Fourier series expansion for $\displaystyle f(t) = t^2 $ in  $\displaystyle 0 < t < 2.$

I know I need to use $\displaystyle ∑ B_n \sin\left(\frac{nπt}{2}\right)$

I know the answer for $\displaystyle B_n$ is $\displaystyle -\frac{8n}{nπ}$ for even $\displaystyle n$ and $\displaystyle \frac{8}{nπ}-\frac{32}{n^3π^3}$ for odd $\displaystyle n$, but I have no clue how to get there. Thanks for the help.

Comment: My apologies for the messy formatting.  I am working on improving it right now - I'm new to this coding, sorry!

Comment: have you studied fourier series before? also, are you familiar with the concept of orthogonal functions?

Comment: I've just started to learn fourier series, and orthogonal functions doesn't ring a bell - have I missed something?

I know that I need to do something different for a period of 2L, and I know I need to use an equation I'm going to edit into the problem right now.

Comment: @Outlaw94: I edited your post. Make sure that's what you mean to ask.

Comment: For odd $n$, it should be $ \frac{8}{nπ}-\frac{32}{n^3π^3} $.

Comment: Thank you.  I corrected my mistake.

Comment: Shouldn't $L=1$?

Comment: I thought L=2.  Did I make a mistake?  How did you find out that L=1?

Comment: Sorry, you are right.

Comment: So you are done! Just plug in the coefficients you found in the series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a general term for $B_n$

$$ B_n = 8\,{\frac { \left( -1 \right) ^{n+1}{n}^{2}{\pi }^{2}+2\, \left( -1
 \right) ^{n}-2}{{n}^{3}{\pi }^{3}}}.$$

Now, the Fourier series is given by

$$ t^2 = 8\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\,{\frac { \left( -1 \right) ^{n+1}{n}^{2}{\pi }^{2}+2\, \left( -1
 \right) ^{n}-2}{{n}^{3}{\pi }^{3}}} \sin\left( \frac{n\pi t}{2}\right). $$

You can split the above series for even and odd $n$ if you want.

Comment: Ah, I see where I made my mistake when I attempted the problem on my own.  Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: @Outlaw94: You are welcome.

Comment: Thanks Dr. for that remarking point on my aswer.+1

Comment: @BabakS.: You are very welcome.